# Created "reduced-gravity-manufacturing" tag but then noticed "manufacture" tag exists, what to do?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I just created a [reduced-gravity-manufacturing](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reduced-gravity-manufacturing) tag to go along with the [reduced-gravity-sports](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reduced-gravity-sports) and [reduced-gravity-cooking](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reduced-gravity-cooking) tags and then enthusiastically added it to eight questions.

On the last one I finally noticed that [manufacture](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manufacture) tag exists already, but currently both tags only exist on three questions.

[manufacture](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manufacture) already has a somewhat ambiguous Wiki excerpt:

> Related to the fabrication of products in space, or the techniques and logistics of production of rockets in series.

It mentions manufacturing in space, but it also talks about "techniques and logistics of production of rockets" without reference to doing it in space. So it seems like a dual-use tag.

Most uses of [manufacture](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manufacture) do seem to relate to conventional manufacturing on Earth.

The way I propose to resolve this is to move all questions about *manufacturing in space* to [reduced-gravity-manufacturing](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reduced-gravity-manufacturing) and all questions about manufacturing *on Earth* of rockets or spaceflight-related items to [manufacture](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manufacture).

Comment: Related issue that's been bothering me: Why is it called "manufacture" instead of "manufacturing"?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that tag is mostly used for Earth-based manufacturing, and it would be nice to have an individual tag specifically for space-based manufacturing.

Comment: I've gone ahead and made some adjustments and posted as an [answer](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1330/12102).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [the other answer](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1313/12102) I've done the following:

I've modified the tag definitions:

For [manufacture](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manufacture):

> Related to the fabrication of products to be used in spaceflight, or the techniques and logistics of production of spaceflight-related items.

For [reduced-gravity-manufacturing](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reduced-gravity-manufacturing):

> Related to the manufacturing of products in reduced gravity environments and/or during spaceflight, or the techniques and logistics thereof.

---

I've also made some tagging adjustments:

Switched to or added [reduced-gravity-manufacturing](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reduced-gravity-manufacturing) or [manufacture](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manufacture) removed

- [Comparing gravity wells: Earth from the Moon vs Surface of Mars](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31084/12102)
- [Which 3D printing technology will Archinaut vessel use?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30110/12102)
- [3D metal printer in microgravity possible?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30075/12102)
- [What was being manufactured on Salyut and Mir?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12777/12102)
- [Manufacturing solar cells on the Moon](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8914/12102)
- [Is there likely to be much nitrogen in the Moon's inner crust?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37411/12102)
- [Where will we get nitrogen in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37125/12102)

Switched to both tags

- [What engineering processes (satellite/space vehicle related) require an atmosphere](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9644/12102)
- [Examples of space research applied to Earthly manufacturing](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36909/12102)

Left as [manufacture](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manufacture)

- [Satellite manufacture and cleanliness](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23792/12102)
- [Was CNC milling used in the 1960's for making the Apollo/Saturn rocket engines?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21825/12102)
- [Why is the cubesat structure so expensive?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19801/12102)
- [What makes a payload fairing so expensive?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14780/12102)
- [Technical reasons for Delta 4 medium phase out](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13811/12102)
- [How much of SpaceX's Falcon 9 launch vehicle and Dragon capsule are 3D printed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13097/12102)
- [Mass manufacturing of satellites](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32880/12102)
- [Is OSIRIS-REx's high gain antenna nearly the same as TESS'? If so, why?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33432/12102)
- [Who were the major manufacturers of the Apollo 11 rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33762/12102)
- [Which Apollo-era contractors are still building aerospace components today?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36469/12102)
- [Were Soviet spacecraft production facilities as widely dispersed as American production facilites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36864/12102)

Comment: Great work! ...

Comment: @uhoh https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microgravity + https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manufacture may work too :).