# "manufacturing" as a synonym for tag "manufacture"

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Could we either rename or make a synonym [manufacturing](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manufacturing) for the existing tag [manufacture](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manufacture)?

Apparently I haven't asked/answered enough questions *specifically with that tag* to even *suggest* a tag synonym.

Comment: related: [Created “reduced-gravity-manufacturing” tag but then noticed “manufacture” tag exists, what to do?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1312/12102)

Answer (score 5):

I merged [manufacture](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manufacture) into [manufacturing](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manufacturing) and created a synonym.